# Как сделать так чтобы выводил от 7 до 0

Tags: java

```java
public class App {
    int[] arr = new int[8];

    void start() {
        nazovi();
        print();
    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    void nazovi() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int startNumb = 7; Stream.iterate(startNumb, i->i-1).limit(startNumb+1).forEach(System.out::println);

Answer (score 3):

Не могу прокомментировать ответ выше из-за баллов репутации. Но в целом он верен, только не соблюдено условие, что 0 выводится тоже. Поэтому скопирую его с правками.

```
void print() {
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: даа спасибо, тоже заметил. Уже исправил сам. В любом случае спасибо вам обоим

Comment: исправил, писал на автомате. без тестов и всего такого

Comment: Вообще, лучше было оставить комментарий под ответом, а не дублировать его =/

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik,  я же написала, что не могу оставить комментарий под ответом (не хватает баллов репутации). Чтобы указать на неточность, пришлось скопировать ответ, что я в принципе тоже указала.

Comment: @azlov проглядел D:

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
void print() {
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```